# SQL alternative to double subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I have a table `MyTable` with values that look like this:

```
|   id    |   name    |    type    |  category    |
---------------------------------------------------
|   1     |   Rob     |   Red      |     Rock     |
|   2     |   Rob     |   Blue     |     Rap      |
|   2     |   Rob     |   Blue     |     Rock     |
|   3     |  Jane     |   Green    |     Country  |
|   3     |  Jane     |   Green    |     Rap      |
|   4     |   Meg     |   Yellow   |     Rock     |
|   5     |  Jane     |   Blue     |     Rap      |
|   5     |  Jane     |   Blue     |     Rock     |
|   6     |  Jane     |   Red      |     Country  |
|   6     |  Jane     |   Red      |     Rock     |
|   7     |  Rob      |   Red      |     Rap      |
|   7     |  Rob      |   Red      |     Country  |
|   8     |  Meg      |   Green    |     Country  |
|   9     |  Meg      |   Blue     |     Rap      |
```

Now, my issue resides in the fact that (as the data is given to me), there are duplicate ids. Each id stands for a report, so id of 1 is for report 1. In this report, there is a `name`, `type`, and `category`. The report can only have one type, but as many categories as it likes. Hence, the duplicate ids come from there being different categories, each constituting a new row. The end result i wish to achieve it to list the names in one row, along with all the types + count (where count is the count of the distinct types, as in one type per report) in the next row. It would look like such:

```
|   Rob    |  Red(2), Blue(1)             |
|   Jane   |  Green(1), Blue(1), Red(1)   |
|   Meg    |  Yellow(1), Green(1), Blue(1)|
```

Now, I've developed a query that actually uses two subqueries and successfully achieves this result. It goes

```
   select name as firstCol, group_concat(type_counts order by countName desc           separator ', ') as secondCol from
   (select name, concat(type,' (',count(name),')') as  type_counts, count(name) as countName from
   (select name, type from 
   some join stuff
   where (date_reported between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-31')
   group by id order by type, name) a
   group by name, type order by name, count(name) desc) a
   group by name;
```

This query essentially groups by id first, to remove the duplicate ids and disregard the split due to differing categories. The query wrapping it then groups by name and traffic type, concatenating the traffic type and the count of names together as "type (count)". The third groups solely by name and group concats all of the types to have a column for the name, and then a second column with all of the type+counts listed and separated by commas. I was just wondering...is there a query that could make it faster, by not having to use so many subqueries and such? Thanks.

Comment: Start with the innermost subquery -- run it and see if it did what you want.  Then move out.

Comment: "Faster"?  Does it take more than a few milliseconds?  How many rows in the table?

Answer (score 0):

> The end result i wish to achieve it to list the names in one row, along with all the types + count (where count is the count of the distinct types, as in one type per report) in the next row.

Use a subquery as an expression in the SELECT clause and another in the WHERE clause. For example:

```
SELECT B.Name, B.UserId AS [User Link], (SELECT Count(B2.Name) FROM Badges B2 WHERE B2.Name = B.Name) as [Total Gold, Silver, and Bronze Badges Awarded for this Tag]
FROM Badges B
WHERE Class = 2
AND TagBased = 1
AND (SELECT Count(B2.Name)
     FROM Badges B2
     WHERE B2.Name = B.Name
     AND B2.Class = 2
     AND B2.TagBased = 1) = 1
GROUP BY B.Name, B.UserId
ORDER BY B.Name
```

**References**

- [Users with their own Silver Tag Badges - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/559288/users-with-their-own-silver-tag-badges)
- [Relational Algebra and SQL (pdf)](http://www.itu.dk/people/pagh/IDB05/Algebra.pdf)
- [A Gentle Introduction to SQL](http://cs.slu.edu/~goldwamh/class/slu/csci371/2005_Fall/lectures/sqlquery/)